# conditionally render !important inline style

Tags: reactjs

If a user selects they want a background colour I want to set the style as bg-primary but if they then select a custom color, the style should override the class. If I drop the `!important` I can see the style is there but because not important it doesn't change the colour. The below code though doesn't set the style at all.

```
style={{ backgroundColor: bgCol && `${bgCol} !important` }}
className={`${showShadow ? "shadow" : ""} ${
    setBgCol ? "bg-primary" : ""
}`}
```

Comment: How do you check if the color is custom or not?

Comment: This seems like an [xy question](http://xyproblem.info) that likely has a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html), *Note that returning a falsy expression will still cause the element after && to be skipped but will return the falsy expression.*

So, it's probably returning `bgCol` and not `!important` because it's resolving as falsy **(an empty string is falsy)**, which could be confusing.

I think it's just an error in the way you're setting the conditional application of `bgCol`. Try using a standard ternary condition:

```
style={{ backgroundColor: (bgCol == "") ? "" : `${bgCol} !important` }}
 className={`${showShadow ? "shadow" : ""} ${
 setBgCol ? "bg-primary" : ""
}`}
```

**NOTE:** You may need to change the ternary condition depending on how you set the initial state of `bgCol`. You could still use `&&` as well, just need to ensure you don't return a falsy expression.

Comment: After having a dig around, it would seem that with React inline `style` you can't set `!important`. Not sure how true that is but it seems true since doing a basic test with it doesn't actually work

Comment: I have ended up using `useRef` and `useEffect` to set the style property `ref.current.style.setProperty("background", bgCol, "important");`